# com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest error when staging Dataflow to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run my Java Dataflow with the DataflowRunner on GCP.

Dataflow works fine with DirectRunner but when changing to DataflowRunner and running it, the console starts staging the files and I suddenly I get the following error several times:

```
mars 19, 2018 8:43:56 PM com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
AVERTISSEMENT: exception thrown while executing request
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But the staging continues (as the console still outputs some staging info) and at some point the errors pops again (may be for the 5th time) and then the following:

```
mars 19, 2018 8:48:13 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFOS: Still staging 127 files
```

As the console says that it is still staging and don't understand whether this is staging issue or related to the execution of my code...

Any idea about it and how to solve this?

** EDIT **
There is another error that I didn't notice before:

```
mars 19, 2018 9:41:46 PM com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
AVERTISSEMENT: exception thrown while executing request
java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3540)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's hard to debug without more information. The staging is where it uploads the files, so if it is stalled it's unlikely to be related to your pipeline code. More likely to be related to the environment and GCS (like permissions on your staging directory).

I would expect it to retry though. Do the files appear on GCS?

Comment: 116 files over 127 are actually staged to the GCS staging location I defined in the Run Configuration... What could I provide to make it easier for you to help?

Comment: Have you tried re-running? Does it always upload 116 files? Are those uploaded immediately and it stalls at 116? What is the staging directory?

Comment: I tried to re-run and even create a new project (just in case) but still the same... if I let the staging run I end up with 127 files over 127 but console stil display `INFOS: Still staging 127 files`. It might be because some of the files are not properly staged (see the insufficient data written error)... The staging directory is as follows: gs://<mybucket>/staging (Multi-regional - US Central)

Comment: I looks like it is not related to my code as the same errors occur with the WordCount example

Comment: @LaraSchmidt it looks like it is related to a networking latency. I manage to stage the dataflow through a compute engine instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a networking issue. Workaround solution is to deploy the pipeline through a Compute Engine instance. This will assure you a good network bandwidth.